# Вернуться на предыдущий шаг FSM aiogram telegram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Помогите, пожалуйста
Есть бот, где пошагово даются инструкции, возникла проблема с реализацией кнопки "Назад", по задумке при нажатии этой клавиши пользователя должно вернуть на шаг назад и предложить выбор выбрать вариант ответа заново, я думал сделать это с помощью `await Form.step2.set()`, но обработка произойдет только при следующем шаге. Как сделать чтоб нажатие именно клавиши "Назад" обрабатывалось сразу?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, selective=True)
    markup.add("Чек-лист")
    await message.reply(config["step1"], reply_markup=markup)
    await Form.step1.set()
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.step1)
async def step1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(step1="done")
    await Form.step2.set()
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, selective=True)
    markup.add("Документы собраны")
    markup.add("Возникли вопросы по поводу документов")
    await message.reply(config["step2"], reply_markup=markup)
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.step2)
async def step2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await Form.step3.set()
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, selective=True)
    markup.add("Вебинар прослушан")
    markup.add("Назад")
    await message.reply(config["step4"], reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажись так

`await Form.previous()`